# How would I initialize a string in Jframe?

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to programming, and I can't seem to figure out how to initialize a String on JFrame Form. I do not know what code to put in to initialize the String if the contents of the string is entered later, by the user. This basically means that the String (stringone) is currently a blank text field on my form. The user enters a sentence or string and the label (one) tells how many characters are in the string they just entered. Here is my code so far:

```
{String stringone = new String ();
int one;

one = Integer.parseInt(txtstringone.getText());

one = (stringone.length());

lblone.setText(String.valueOf(one));}
```

Currently there is a yellow line under the third line of code, saying it may not have been initialized. It also does not work when I run it. Hope this clears it up!
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: *"the string is entered later, by the user"* - How does the user enter the string? It's difficult to tell what is being asked here but maybe this can begin to clarify

Comment: Does any error show up?

Comment: Your question is terribly unclear. Is the purpose of the String to set a label on your JFrame? If so, there's no need to initialize anything. Why don't you take the time to explain your problem more completely and simply describe in detail what you're trying to do without getting into all of the programming particulars.

Comment: Does the error show up on this line? one = Integer.parseInt(txtstringone.getText()) ??

Comment: Yes it does show on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String stringone;
```

Remove **new String()**

If you want to initialize it, tou must pass it a String value. For example:

```
String stringone = "value";
```

The string's length (stringone.length()), will be 5.

So, in order to take the length of a String you must first initialize it. Otherwise, it will be null, and null does not have length.

Comment: Yes, i need to take the length of stringone, how would I initialize it?

Comment: When we say to initialize, we mean to give it a value. For example: String stringone = "value". Then, stringone.length() will be 5

Comment: Yes, however the value  changes based on what the user enters in the text field. Since I don't know what they may enter, I don't know how to initialize it because I cannot give it a value.

Comment: You can check if user has given a value. if(stringone.equals("")) then ... In other words, you check if string is null. If it is null, you can give 0, as the length.

Answer (score 0):

> The user enters a sentence or string and the label (one) tells how many characters are in the string they just entered.

What you need to do is add an *event handler* for when the user has entered the string. There is no "user entered string" before the user has given the string.

An event handler is code that runs when some "event" occurs. A user writing in a field is a possible event.

Here's how you can add an event listener on your `txtstringone` text field component. It will be triggered when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

```
txtstringone = new JTextField();
txtstringone.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String text = txtstringone.getText();
        int one = text.length();
        lblone.setText(String.valueOf(one));
    }
});
```

You can find a longer tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html and a short working program at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextDemoProject/src/components/TextDemo.java